# proof by induction: product of number = 1

Tags: logic, induction

Before anything, sorry if I make any phrasing mistakes. I'm not 100% comfortable with writing in English.

So here's my problem. I don't want the resolution but just a hint on how to proceed for solving it.

> For any $n \in \mathbb N$, for any $r_1, r_2, \dots , r_n \in \mathbb R$ such that $\forall i, 1 \le i \le n, r_i > 0$ and $r_1 \times r_2 \times \dots \times r_n = 1$, if $\exists i, 1 \le i \le n$ such that $r_i < 1$, then $\exists j, 1 \le j \le n$ such that $r_j > 1$.

I'm pretty sure it's an induction problem since I need to prove that the hypothesis is true for any $n$.

**How I started:**

$A(n) = (\exists i, 1 \le i \le n ∣ r_i < 1) \rightarrow (\exists j, 1 \le j \le n ∣ r_j > 1)$

Hypothesis:
For any $n \in \mathbb N$, for any $r_1, r_2, \dots , r_n \in \mathbb R$ such that $\forall i, 1 \le i \le n, r_i > 0$ and $r_1 \times r_2 \times \dots \times r_n = 1, A(n)$

Basis step ($ n=1 $):

We have $r_1 = 1$ since the product of the $r_i $ equals $ 1$,
therefore since there's only one number ($r_1 = 1$) there's no number $ \ne 1$. Therefore we have $\mathrm {fasle} \rightarrow \mathrm {false}$, so $A(1)$ is true.
The basis step is verified.

Let's suppose $A(n)$ is true for $n = k$ (an arbitrary positive integer), then we must show that $A(n)$ is true for $n = k + 1$.

And this is where I'm blocked. I can't find a way to show that if there's a number $< 1$ in the $r_i$ there's necessarily a number $> 1$. And maybe I've made a mistake in my basis step but I can't find where.

Any hint on how to progress or why my reasoning is wrong would be very appreciated.

Thank you very much!

Comment: This question has severe formatting or content problems. This question is unlikely to be salvageable through editing, and might need to be removed.

Comment: To fix formatting, use math jax https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Thank you I'm updating my post now

Comment: You prove by contradiction: it all $r$ are smaller [resp. larger] than $1$, their product is smaller [resp. larger] than $1$.

Comment: ok for prooving by contradiction:
$\neg A(n)$ would be:
$ (∃i,1 ≤ i ≤ n ∣ r{_i} < 1 ) \wedge ( ∀j,1 ≤ j ≤ n ∣ r{_j} < 1)$
rigth ? 
the problem is that this is false since the product of number $<1$ is necessecarilly $<1$ too so it's not a contradiction of the from $r \wedge \neg r$

Answer (score 1):

It's actually easier: if  $\exists i :r_i<1$ and if we assume that $0<r_j\leq1 \forall j\neq i$, then the product would be $<1\cdot1\cdot\dots1=1$

Comment: So the proof by induction is not the good way to go?

Comment: There's no need for it and to be honest, I think it's a bad way to approach the problem

Comment: No, that's a proof by induction but on an easier equivalent statement.

Comment: The "induction" is on: if $r_i\le 1$ then $r_1r_2...r_3\le 1*1*1.....*1$.  We know that is true for the product of two terms (it's an inequality axiom) but via induction we can see it must be also true for all finite products.

Answer (score 0):

Try proving the equivalent contrapositive:

If $0 <r_i \le 1$ for all $i$ then $\prod r_i \le 1$ and if any $r_k<1$ then $\prod r_i <1$.

And that is easier if we prove the stronger:

If $0 <r_i\le 1$ for all $i $ then $\prod r_i \le \min (r_i)\le 1$.

Proof:  $n=1$ obvious.

$r_1=\min(r_i)\le 1$

$n=2$.  If $0 <r_1\le 1$ and $0 <r_2\le 1$, then $r_1r_2\le r_1*1=r_1\le 1$. Also $r_1r_2\le 1*r_2 =r_2\le 1$  so $r_1r_2\le \min (r_i)\le 1$

Inductive step:

If $\prod r_i \le \min r_i $ for $1\le i\le n $ and if $0 <r_{n+1}\le 1$ then

$(\prod r_i) *r_{n+1}\le 1*r_{n+1}=r_{n+1}\le 1$.

And $(\prod r_i) *r_{n+1}\le (\prod r_i*1\le \min (r_i)\le 1$.

So $(\prod r_i) *r_{n+1}\le \min (\min r_i, r_{n+1})=\min_{i\le n+1}r_i\le 1$.

QED.

This proves your result.  If $\prod r_i =1$ but some $r_k <1$ then if all $r_i\le 1$ we'd have $\prod r_i \le r_k <1$.  Since that didn't happen so $p_m > 1$ for some $m $.

Comment: Thank you very much, super helpful.